# VBA fill a range with a specific cell

Tags: vba, excel

In a worksheets i have "Dates" in `Cells(1,1)`, `Cells(1,10)`, `Cells(1,19)`, `Cells(1,28)` .....

I have a variable named `nr_rows` witch in my case is 860, and i need to put under every "Dates" the results from `Row 1` in `Row 2` until `Row 860`.

The results must be like:

```
       |       A         |       J          |      S           |.....
-----------------------------------------------------------
  1    |  21.02.16 16:20 |  21.02.16 16:21  |  21.02.16 16:22  |.....
  2    |  21.02.16 16:20 |  21.02.16 16:21  |  21.02.16 16:22  |.....
  3    |  21.02.16 16:20 |  21.02.16 16:21  |  21.02.16 16:22  |.....
.....................................................................
860    |  21.02.16 16:20 |  21.02.16 16:21  |  21.02.16 16:22  |.....
```

This i what i have done but i have error `1004`

`nr_rows is 860`

```
col = 1
For col = 1 To 256
    For n = 1 to nr_rows

ActiveSheet.Cells(1, col).Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(1, col), Cells(n,col))
    col = col + 9

    Next n
Next col
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edited** after OP's clarifications about quitting `AutoFill()` method

use this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim nr_rows As Long, col As Long

    nr_rows = 860
    With ActiveSheet
        For col = 1 To 256 Step 9
            .Cells(1, col).Resize(nr_rows).Value = .Cells(1, col).Value
        Next col
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: it was the best I could do with input data as per your question. you may want to both improve it with detailed description of a "before" and "after" scenario and give more detail about what _"still no results"_ actually means

Comment: The query don't copy the results from row 1, he increase the datetime. For example for column 1 i have this results:
21.02.2016 16:00
21.02.2016 16:01
21.02.2016 16:02......

Comment: My apologies, your query is good, but i think autofill is not a good ideea, because increase the datetime

Comment: see edited answer. Anyhow, since my previous answer already solved your _original_ question, you might want to mark it as accepted. thank you